# 'at' command intended behaviour? Launching each commands instead of scheduling

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, scheduled-tasks, at

I'm trying to schedule the execution of some programs. I'm using this command:

```
./tests.o | at 15:00&
```

If I understood correctly, the intended behaviour was to delay execution until 15:00. However if I run `top` as soon as I launch the above command, I can see already tests.o eating CPU time.

Since I need to launch multiple tests on a shared resources I am wondering how to correctly use "at"?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This syntax (excluding `&` which is not needed) would be right if `./tests.o` generated (printed to its stdout) the commands you want to run at 15:00.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`at` reads commands from standard input. What you are doing is running `./tests.o` and feeding its *output* string(s) as command(s) for `at` to schedule. Also, there is no need for the trailing `&`, as `at` returns immediately.

What you need is:

```
echo ./tests.o | at 15:00
```

or:

```
at 15:00 <<< ./tests.o
```

You will need to use quoting if you want the scheduled command to use redirection or other shell functions, eg:

```
at 15:00 <<< './tests.o > tests.log'
```

Comment: Thanks, now i see what i was doing wrong. @KamilMaciorowski thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I often cross with other answers and comments, as I frequently realise there are things I should double-check while I'm writing my answer. I don't always remember to check before I post. Sorry to have pipped you at the post.

Comment: A here-document is another convenient way to deal with shell metacharacters in the command.

Comment: @Barmar - I used a here-string in my answer and this was the right answer for the problem posed in the question, but obviously a here-document would be appropriate if more than one command was to be scheduled at the same time. I wouldn't use it for a single command in order to avoid quoting.

Comment: I'm not criticizing, just mentioning an alternative that generalizes a little better.

Comment: @Barmar - I realised that, and I was trying to qualify your comment by illustrating where it would be more relevant.